# Struggling little with MySQL insertion

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying a php code to insert record into a table.

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db_con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
$select_db = mysql_select_db("test_database",$db_con);
$txnid = date ("ydmHis") . mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$custnumber = "4316010100000001";
$cust_mo_num = "7875432990";
$bc_id = "LTH001";
$timestamp = "12:12:12:12:12:12";
$amounta = "500";
$txnupdate = "INSERT INTO cust_txn (txnid,cust_num,cust_mo_num,bc_username,txn_time,txn_amount,txn_type,txn_status) VALUES ('$txnid','$custnumber','$cust_mo_num','$bc_id','$timestamp','$amounta','WTH','SUCC')";
$result = mysql_query($txnupdate);
mysql_close($db_con);
echo $result;
?>
```

When I run this page and refresh it, the record is inserted only once. (The txnid is primary key and I do change it every time.) I have no way to know where am I going wrong.

Comment: "(The txnid is primary key and I do change it every time.)" If that is true, then the code you posted isn't the same code as you are running. The code you posted obviously won't work. But it might be a bit hard to see the problem in your actual code if we don't know how it differs from the code you posted. Can you please post your actual code?

Comment: Post your create table statement here after running below command in mysql console.

show create table cust_txn;

Comment: mysql_select_db("test_database", $con);
$sql5 = "CREATE TABLE CUST_TXN 
(
txnid char(16),
PRIMARY KEY(txnid),
cust_num char(16),
cust_mo_num char(10),
bc_username char(6),
txn_time varchar(18),
txn_amount varchar(10),
txn_type varchar(5),
txn_status varchar(10)
 
)";

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($sql5,$con)) 
{
echo "CUST_TXN Table created \r\n";
echo "<br/>";
}

else
{
die (mysql_error());
//continue;
}

Comment: @MarkByers: I have modified the code. the $txnid changes with every refresh.

Comment: @user1051505 - your `CREATE TABLE` code would be better edited into your question, rather than in the comments, so it can be formatted and presented as part of the original problem.

Comment: @MarkByers: Hey it's working. My table name was similar to a different table name. I am extremely sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I just capitalize table name since i'm using ubunthu box. (Your create table statement provided with CUST_TXN table name)

**SOURCE**

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pwd = "root123";
$db_con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
$select_db = mysql_select_db("ci",$db_con);
$txnid = date ("ydmHis") . mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$custnumber = "4316010100000001";
$cust_mo_num = "7875432990";
$bc_id = "LTH001";
$timestamp = "12:12:12:12:12:12";
$amounta = "500";
$txnupdate = "INSERT INTO CUST_TXN (txnid,cust_num,cust_mo_num,bc_username,txn_time,txn_amount,txn_type,txn_status) VALUES ('$txnid','$custnumber','$cust_mo_num','$bc_id','$timestamp','$amounta','WTH','SUCC')";
echo $txnupdate;
$result = mysql_query($txnupdate);
mysql_close($db_con);
echo $result;
?>
```

**RESULTS**

```
> select * from CUST_TXN;
+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------+------------+
| txnid            | cust_num         | cust_mo_num | bc_username | txn_time          | txn_amount | txn_type | txn_status |
+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1209042028162311 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 12:12:12:12:12:12 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042028177407 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 12:12:12:12:12:12 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042028194204 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 12:12:12:12:12:12 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042028342444 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 12:12:12:12:12:12 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042028358383 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 12:12:12:12:12:12 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042028362068 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 12:12:12:12:12:12 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Also you can use current_timestamp for your txn_time column

**MYSQL DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE CUST_TXN_2 ( txnid char(16), PRIMARY KEY(txnid), cust_num char(16), cust_mo_num char(10), bc_username char(6), txn_time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, txn_amount varchar(10), txn_type varchar(5), txn_status varchar(10) );
```

**SOURCE**

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pwd = "root123";
$db_con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
$select_db = mysql_select_db("ci",$db_con);
$txnid = date ("ydmHis") . mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$custnumber = "4316010100000001";
$cust_mo_num = "7875432990";
$bc_id = "LTH001";
$amounta = "500";
$txnupdate = "INSERT INTO CUST_TXN_2 (txnid,cust_num,cust_mo_num,bc_username,txn_amount,txn_type,txn_status) VALUES ('$txnid','$custnumber','$cust_mo_num','$bc_id','$amounta','WTH','SUCC')";
echo $txnupdate;
$result = mysql_query($txnupdate);
mysql_close($db_con);
echo $result;
?>
```

**RESULTS**

```
> select * from CUST_TXN_2;
+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+
| txnid            | cust_num         | cust_mo_num | bc_username | txn_time            | txn_amount | txn_type | txn_status |
+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1209042055524683 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 2012-04-09 20:55:52 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042055563581 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 2012-04-09 20:55:56 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042055564435 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 2012-04-09 20:55:56 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
| 1209042055579931 | 4316010100000001 | 7875432990  | LTH001      | 2012-04-09 20:55:57 | 500        | WTH      | SUCC       |
+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the timestamp suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

$txnid sounds like timestamp. Mysql can insert it automatically. Set it as

ALTER TABLE `CUST_TXN` CHANGE `txnid` `txnid` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

You will not longer set timestamp in code.